# How do I get the path to SPM when I perform a archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager, wireguard

I am now trying to use `WireGuardKit`, where it asks to create an "External Build System" and fill in the `Directory` with `${BUILD_DIR}/... /... /SourcePackages/checkouts/wireguard/Sources/WireGuardKitGo` (this path has been modified and I guarantee that this path will allow me to pass the compilation).

However, when I execute archive, Xcode reports an error `unable to spawn process '/usr/bin/make' (No such file or directory)`.

I suspect that `$(BUILD_DIR)` doesn't have a value when the compilation is executed, or I can't use this environment variable at this stage. Because when I don't use relative paths and use absolute paths to assign values to `Directory`, the project is able to archive successfully.

So my question is, when I execute the archive, how do I get the path of the package I inherited using SPM? Or can I use `$(BUILD_DIR)` environment variable when I execute archive? Why is it different from when compiling?

**UPDATE**:

I learned that `$(BUILD_DIR)` uses `$()` within it and when I try to use `$()` directly, it still reports an error, I also tried variables like `$(BUILD_PATH)`, `$(BUILD_ROOT)`, `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)`, but none of them work.

So could it be a problem with `$()`, an environment variable that has no value when the archive is executed?

How do I get the SPM directory when executing the archive?

Comment: Try `"${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with an alternative configuration for External Build System

[Here is a tutorial](https://github.com/passepartoutvpn/tunnelkit#manual-xcode-steps) (see section "Manual Xcode steps")

The main idea is to use [build_wireguard_go_bridge.sh](https://github.com/passepartoutvpn/tunnelkit/blob/master/Scripts/build_wireguard_go_bridge.sh) script in your External Build System configuration:

Build Tool: `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Scripts/build_wireguard_go_bridge.sh`

Arguments: `$(ACTION)`

Directory: `<empty>`

Comment: I changed the external build system like you said, but I get an error: unable to spawn process '.../wireguard-apple/Scripts/build_wireguard_go_bridge.sh' (Permission denied). Any idea why permission would be denied?

Comment: @shirefriendship try chmod +x build_wireguard_go_bridge.sh